# Printing .DOC with variable height in continuous paper (paper roll) with "Aspose Words"

Tags: c#, aspose.words

I'm programatically building a .DOC (using Aspose Words) with variable height according with the contents that will be printed, and it will be printed in a roll of paper (see thermal printers).

What kind of approach should I take ? I thought two ways: Create a paper with a minimum height but with zero top and bottom margins, so the pages could have the effect of being in the same page, or dynamically change the page height ?

Any solution is welcome, and of course how to do them. But I would prefer to have the doc inside a unique page (long as needed), because these printers can cut the paper in some events, like on each page break (hardware/driver feature out of the application control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got success with the approach to stretch the page to fit the contents in only 1 page. However, as the Aspose Words doesn't seem to have ways to measure the remaining space of the last page in the Aspose Words API, I worked around in this way:

I defined the document page height multiplying the PageCount by the useful page height (margins subtracted), and so, applied tries to adjust the remaining space dividing the useful page height by 2 on each try and increasing or decreasing it, like the foundation of any ordinary binary search algorithm.

It works, and how the foundation of binary algorithms has a logarithmic scale, in the worse case it will cost me less than 10 tries to fit the page (my useful height won't exceed 30cm, but even thus, if it had 1 meter will cost about 14 tries at the worse case).